# How can I customize the GNOME Shell Messaging Tray?

Tags: gnome, customization, messaging-tray

I'm using GNOME Shell and have some questions about customization that I think will be cool to try. For example, the Messaging Tray shows only the icon of the program (Dropbox, Google Chrome, etc), and when you got the mouse hovering over it, it shows the icon AND the name; for example Icon + Icon Name. Is it possible to always show only the icon or always show the icon + icon name?

I really think this status bar can have more things, like shortcuts, or something else. Is it possible to manually add something to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell: GNOME Shell allows for very limited customization (by design) and the system tray is not one of those areas. In fact the very fact that it exists is only to support certain legacy applications (to a large extent).

If you want to customize it, you will need to write an extension (or ask someone to do it), which shouldn't be too hard, because it's all Javascript :)!
See here for reference: http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions

Comment: Hmmm... And where I can find something with reference to write/create those extensions?

Comment: @euDennis see my update.